# Enabling sqlite3 in php7

Tags: linux, php7, sqlite

I want to enable sqlite3 in php.ini but when I try to load a PHP script this error happens:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/sqlite.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/sqlite.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/pdo_sqlite.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/pdo_sqlite.so: undefined symbol: php_pdo_unregister_driver in Unknown on line 0
```

But the library in this path exists

```
/usr/lib/php/20151012/sqlite.so
```

In only change this line in my php.ini

```
extension=pdo_sqlite.so
```

My OS is: Debian GNU/Linux 9.4 (stretch)

Answer (score 7):

Make sure the correct package is installed and apache restarted after:

```
sudo apt install php7.0-sqlite3
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

If that didn't work:

Then, correct the name for the extension in `php.ini` to:

```
extension=sqlite3.so
extension=pdo_sqlite.so
```

And restart apache again: `sudo systemctl restart apache2`

Comment: same error

`
 [Thu Jun 21 23:10:18.114761 2018] [:error] [pid 7299] [client 187.211.175.243:50242] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file in /var/www/html/dist/includes/database.inc.php:30\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/dist/includes/database.inc.php(30): PDO->__construct('sqlite:/var/db/...', 'null', 'null')\n#1 /var/www/html/dist/upload.php(12): require_once('/var/www/html/d...')\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/dist/includes/database.inc.php on line 30`

Comment: @JorgeEduardoTiradoSandoval that doesn't seem to be the same error. It's reporting that you have a problem with the database and the file you are calling it from, there is no issue with the library now. I think it's another problem now.